# How can I expand Excel datasets that have formulas attached?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to work with some relatively simple datasets in Excel, but I realized that I don't know how to expand them properly.

See the image below for reference:
 [image: An image of an example dataset]

If I wanted to add a `USER E` or `CAT. 5` to this set, what's the easiest way to do so while keeping all the formulas in tact (and possibly adding the formula for the new row/column automatically)?

Comment: Hi Kona, where is the dataset coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insert a column between D and E, the formulas will not change. They will still reference the columns you referenced before and you will need to update them manually to include the new user E.

If you want the formulas to automatically include data in new columns, the techniques to do that will vary, depending on what sort of references you use in the formulas.

For example, if the formulas in E2 and F2 are, respectively

```
=sum(B2:D2)
=average(B2:D2)
```

Insert a new column E and the formulas will have to be manually adjusted to `=sum(B2:32)`.

Or, you could change the formulas to

```
=sum(B2:index(B:B,column()-1))
=average(B2:index(B:B,column()-1))
```

In words: `Sum everything from B2 to the cell immediately left of the current column` and `average everything from B2 to two cells left of the current column`.

If you have trouble applying that to your scenario, pipe up.

Comment: It took a little bit of finessing (since a row variable seems to be required for the index function) but this worked great for my data set; thanks!

Comment: Index can be used with just two parameters. If the first parameter is a reference to a range in a single column, then the second parameter will be interpreted as the row number. If the first parameter is a reference to a range in a single row, then the second parameter will be interpreted as the column number. If the first parameter is a multi-row and multi-column range, then you need a row AND a column parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a column while conserving all properties of columns to the right:

- Select the column heading to the right of where you want the new column to appear. For example, if you want to insert a new column between columns D and E, select column E.

[image]

- Click the Insert command on the Home tab

[image]

- The new column will appear to the left of the selected column.

[image]

When inserting rows and columns, make sure you select the entire row or column by clicking the heading. If you select only a cell in the row or column, the Insert command will only insert a new cell.

Source:
[Excel 2013 - Modifying Columns, Rows, and Cells](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excel2013/modifying-columns-rows-and-cells/1/).